# how to get activity icon in android mobile

Tags: android, icons

my program is database program, when i run it,
on consol i got message as follow,

```
Uploading DataBase.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-11-08 13:48:03 - DataBase] Installing DataBase.apk...
[2010-11-08 13:48:42 - DataBase] Success!
[2010-11-08 13:48:43 - DataBase] /DataBase/bin/DataBase.apk installed on device
[2010-11-08 13:48:43 - DataBase] Done!
```

but its not run, even its not shown android icon in emulator,
so how come i run it, or how come i get icon on emulator

please help me,
thanx in advance

Comment: We can't help you without code. What were you expecting it to run as and what icon were you expecting to display

Comment: i am doing this developing in eclipse, and when i run by default emulator is open, and in console i got comment as i mention as early, program is not run properly, and click on emulator menu, its show us our program icon plus its own icon also, at that place also i didn,t show my program icon. i will post my code, just check and reply me please